# Why is tesseract not accepting the config?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

Im trying to get tesseract to only recognize numbers but no matter what I put for configuration, it ignores it. pytessseract is in version 0.2.0 and tesseract in 4.00.00alpha

```
from PIL import Image

import pytesseract as tes
import glob

tes.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

a = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Pascal\Desktop\visible\*.png')

for imgPath in a:
    casd = Image.open(imgPath).convert('L').point(lambda x: 0 if x < 200 else 255, '1')
    im = tes.image_to_string(casd, config='outputbase digits')
    print(im)
```

Some outputs:

® a 69 ® 0

® a 69 ® 0

® ase ® 0

® aso ® 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that `digits` config file relies on is broken in Tesseract 4.0x.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in newly released 4.1.0.